# Unexplained, unsolisted downloads

Tags: 14.04, downloads

Recently have been receiving an unexplained download of 12.5Meg on connection to the ISP.

Any way of finding where it's coming from?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Etherape is a really neat monitoring tool to keep tabs on the network, just specify the devices to monitor.

```
sudo apt-get install etherape
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By opening system monitor, (Dash-> Search "System Monitor") and clicking on the "Resources" tag, you can see if your computer is using data. This lets you find if your machine is the cause of the data usage. From there, the program "nethogs" will let you identify processes' individual bandwidth usage. 
http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/

If you would like to firewall programs, I recommend the software gufw, available by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

Hope this helped. Cheers!